# code in HTML for sharing content over Phone gap interacting with other app as like ACTION_SEND indent on the native android code

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova

i am trying to **create an content sharing code in html for mobile** as in the below image for my phone gap application

[image]

i tried various ways, but i am not create sharing content to any app as like the below pic

[image]

help me how to code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for anything like this ? a phone gap plugin for social sharing??  [Phonegap plugin for social sharing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing)

[image: This is a similar view created by using cordova social sharing plugin]

Comment: may be! i need to knew the way to make the sharing exactly like that image above for phonegap html code

Comment: You can use that.I have use the social sharing pluing for cordova in my projects.It results in a same view as you posted